# Enable/Disable Extensions when using VS code

Tags: python, html, visual-studio-code

I have a question about VS code. Since I want to use VS code not only for HTML but also Python, I download extensions for python and enable them. But after I enable them the extensions for HTML doesn't work :( . So I am really curious whether I should disable extensions depending on the language I use in VS code.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that...